# save binary binary columns with numpy

Tags: file, python-3.x, numpy

I read in some binary columns with

```
dtype = ['<f8', '<f8', '<i4']
raw = np.fromfile(file_id, dtype=dtype, count=n_col)
f0 = raw[0]
f1 = raw[1]
i0 = raw[2]
```

Now I only have the `numpy` arrays `f0`, `f1`, `i0`. How would I write them in the same sense to an binary file. It tryed

```
np.array([f0, f1, i0]).tofile(file_id) # Promotes my int32 to double
np.array(tuple([f0, f1, i0]).tofile(file_id) # Does something writing a lot of data, but I have no idea in what structure
```

Any help would be appretiated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution I found would be to first typecast everything into one huge blob of `int32`and then write this down. Since I didn't find any typecast I copy the whole memory. I'm doing something like this:

```
raw = []
# Kind of make a very ugly typecast by using a lot of Memomory
tmp = np.fromstring(f0.tostring(), dtype=np.int32)
raw.append(tmp[::2])
raw.append(tmp[1::2])

... # do the same of f1

raw.append(i0)

# Finaly write it down
np.array(raw).transpose().tofile(file_id)
```

Since this solution is quite ugly memory whise I will not accept it till monday. Maybe somebody can help me out here with a better solution.